# Hive Custom UDF jar gives error for other insert query

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hadoop2

I am checking how to create a custom UDF in Hive. I have created a custom UDF which does nothing, just returns the given text as it is.

- I am able to load this JAR in hive without any issue
- I am also able to create function from this jar and I am able to execute this function.

**Problem**

> if this Jar is added I can't execute load table/hdfs from another table. following simple query fails.

```
insert into demo1 select * from demo;
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1523501275422_0010_3_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1523501275422_0010_3_00_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Container container_1523501275422_0010_01_000007 finished with diagnostics set to [Container completed. ]], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Container container_1523501275422_0010_01_000008 finished with diagnostics set to [Container completed. ]], TaskAttempt 2 failed, info=[Container container_1523501275422_0010_01_000009 finished with diagnostics set to [Container completed. ]], TaskAttempt 3 failed, info=[Container container_1523501275422_0010_01_000010 finished with diagnostics set to [Container completed. ]]], Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1 killedTasks:0, Vertex vertex_1523501275422_0010_3_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]
DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:0
```

Please note that both the table has same structure.

If I remove the jar then I can execute above query without any issue.

**Code:**
**ca.abc.demo**

```
public class demo extends UDF {

    public String evaluate(String s) {
        if (s == null) {
            return null;
        }else{
            return s;
        }

    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ca.cantire</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-normalize</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-exec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>ca.abc.demo</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Your stack trace is generic, you have to dig deeper. Also, try Text datatype instead of String, That might help.

Comment: @Shweta this is only log I can get from yarn.

Comment: what about container/task's logs? You will find more information there.

Comment: @Shweta the only thing I can find in taks logs is `[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 32768K->4674K(37888K)] 32768K->4754K(123904K), 0.0061099 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] `